# Why python tesserocr not using 4 CPU cores on AWS Batch?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, python-tesseract, aws-batch

I'm trying to get tesserocr python library to run on 4 cores. According to tesseract docs, I understand it supports up to 4 cores. I have a tesserocr python3.x job running inside AWS Batch (docker container based on amazonlinux:latest image) on a c4.x2large instance which has 8 vCPUs, all were allocated to the batch job at submission time.

The benchmarks show CPU at 30% max, i.e. 2.5 vCPUs i.e. about 1.25 physical cores (each 2 vCPUs are roughy 1 physical core).

I've also tried the OMP_NUM_THREADS=4, OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=4 environment variables (based on some forum online), but no value had any effect on performance whatsoever.

How do I can tesserocr to scale up to all 4 cores (8 vCPUs)?

Answer (score 0):

Python Threads are not 1:1 with vCPUs / Cores.

If you look at the specifications for a `c4.x2large` instance, it says you can run up to 2 threads per core. And that machine has 8 vCPUs.

To *potentially* use all 8 vCPUs you *could* try setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=16`, `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=16`. However how the underlying `tesserocr` is implemented will have a huge impact on how well it scales within the context of the machine.

Comment: To clarify my issue: seems like those env vars have no impact whatsoever. I tried 12, 16, 24 - no change in run-time or CPU utilization. Do these settings work within a Amazon Linux docker container? Do these require some special tesseract build/settings maybe?